# Dell Optiplex 3020 Motherboard randomly loses power while running

Tags: power-supply

I have a dell optiplex 3020 which has 8 pin power connector motherboard , dell brand 81 motherboard, but few months back my motherboard was suddenly droping power from motherboard and without any shutdown or restart..

then the motherboard randomly gets and lose power. even if the desktop is off and idle it's gets and lose power. That time I changed the power supply and added a 24 pin to 8pin atx converter.

It was working well these few months, but recently I'm facing the same problem, so this time I bought a Thermaltake litepower 450 watt power supply and a new 24pin to 8pin atx converter. But still doesn't fix the issue this time.

But with a new power supply, it runs smoothly for about half an hour and then the problem starts; before changing the power supply, it would only work for 2-3 minutes or sometimes for 10-15 minutes.

Comment: Have you considered the problem is the motherboard not the PSU since you have replaced the PSU several times?

Comment: Indeed ^^^. I would start by checking up the capacitors.